# "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType" how do I fix this this error, can you explain why it's not working

Tags: python

The code is supposed to run through an array 'A' searching for the number of insances of an integer 'k' which it then returns. I have to use recursion and I've already completed the task using for loops. I'm not sure why I'm getting this error and want to understand why it's happening and find a solution. The guides I've read werent clear.

I've tried running 6 variations of the code. This isn't as elegant as the original but should cover every case of input.

```
def o(k,A):
    if len(A) == 1:
        if A[0] == k:
            return 1
        else:
            return
    else:
        if A[0] == k:
            return 1 + o(k,A[1:])
        else:
            return o(k,A[1:])

o(5,[1,2,5,3,6,5,3,5,5,4])
```

I would expect the function to return 4, as there are 4 instances of 5 in the array passed, but it outputs an error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Comment: `else: return` <- this is a bad case, given the callers all expect an integer.

Comment: i had a variation where i explicity stated A[0] != k: with the same return but i had the same error. do you know why im getting the error?

Comment: Because `1 + o(k,A[1:])` is `1 + None` if `len(A[1:]) == 1 and A[0] != k`. Think about the simplest case - what output would you expect for `o(0, [1])`? Do you get it?

Comment: omg i feel stupid now. i assumed that `return` would convert automaticly cos the types are dynamic thanks @jonrsharpe

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your code, please extract and provide a [mcve]. Further, just do a websearch for the error message. Both these measures will probably allow you to fix your problem yourself.

Comment: i did search up the error. i just didnt understand why it wasent working as i assumed the `return` would convert automaticly to zero for int as i thought the types were dynamic. ima have to search up more on it. sorry @urlich Eckhardt  if i did stuff wrong first time posting

Answer (score 0):

```
def o1(k, A, count = 0):
    if len(A) ==0:
        return count

    if (A[0] == k):
        return o1(k, A[1:], count+1)
    else:
        return o1(k, A[1:], count)

o1(5,[1,2,5,3,6,5,3,5,5,4])

Out[1]:
4

o1(6,[1,2,5,3,6,5,3,5,5,4])

Out[2]:
1
```

P.S. This code in a case if you use only recursion.
But of course most simplify solution for this task is:

```
 [1,2,5,3,6,5,3,5,5,4].count(5)

 Out[3]:
 4
```

### About original question

```
def o(k,A):
    if len(A) == 1:
        if A[0] == k:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0   # this explicitly value 0 helps to fixed this error. When you reached the bottom and the last element didn't match the desired value it explicitly return 0
    else:
        if A[0] == k:
            return 1 + o(k,A[1:])
        else:
            return o(k,A[1:])

o(5,[1,2,5,3,6,5,3,5,5,4])

Out[12]:
4
```

Comment: It's helpful to explain what you've changed, and why.

Comment: You right. Actually i give another version of code, to solve this task. I have updated the code, to make it more clear.  Now it has only one additional variable. Which pass to recursion when we diving there deeper - it's a counter which increase when we match the values.

Comment: But it still doesn't explain what was wrong with the OP's code, and how this new version fixes it.

Comment: did additional upd )

Comment: Thanks for this. but im not allowed to change the variables parsed to the function. or use additonal variables. @jonrsharpe helped me realise where i went wrong. but thanks